# редактирвоания json средствами php

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents, fopen

суть вопроса не много не обычная: сделать код красивее и читабеьнее

```php
<?php

$path = '';
if(!file_exists($path)) # используется исключительно для создание файла если он не сушествует
{
    $file = fopen($path, 'a+');
    fclose($file);
    unset($file);
}

$json = file_get_contents($path);
$json = json_decode($json);

...

$json = json_encode($json);
file_put_contents($path, $json);

?>
```

`$json знаю что название переменной оставляет желать лучшего.`
если есть идеи по названию переменной пишите.

```
{
    "id пользователя": {
        [
            "text": "text сообщения"
        ]
    }
}
```

суть проста: в json хранить опубликованный записи пользователя.
нюансом заключается в том что названия файла: xx.xx.xxxx.json то есть дата текушего дня. и только из за этого приходить делать проверку на сушествования файла.

Comment: А в чём вопрос-то?

Comment: сделать код красивее и читабельнее, я просто не могу найти функцию у fopen чтобы считать данные разом

Comment: fopen(); …(); fwrite(); fclose(); навеное конструкция должна быть такая

Comment: Зачем создавать файл если в руководстве `file_put_contents` черным по белому написано "Если filename не существует, файл будет создан."?

Comment: а file_get_contents(); ошибку выдает так как файла не сушествует

Comment: Ну так проверь что файл существует и только потом используй `file_get_contents`.